# Calling different function for different search Option

Tags: php

Dear Friend i have two function and maybe i might have more in the future but the point is that i want when a user searches for hotel based on postal code on the same text field the function 
hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue) should be called and when i search based on country then the function 
hotel_by_country($textvalue) should be called. the following is the code that should displays the result however it is not displayong the result as it should at all.

```
<?php require_once("includes/header.php");?>
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php")?>
<?php    
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          $message =""; 
          $textvalue = $_POST['search'];
          if(empty($allhotels = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue)) || empty($allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue))){
             $message = "There is no record in the database";
          } 

      }else{    
          $allhotels = select_all_hotels();
      } 
?>

<div class="cBoth"></div>
<div id="sep"></div>
<div id="mainContentSection" class="Calign">

<div id="detaillist">

<div id="searching" class="Calign">


  <form action="list2.php" method="POST" id="searchForm">
  <fieldset>
  <input type="text"  name="search" />
  <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Search" /></fieldset>
  </form>      
</div><!--End of searching-->

<?php 
if(isset($message)){
echo"<div id=\"listtitle\">";
echo"<h2>".$message."</h2>";
echo"</div>";//End of listtitle div
}else{
echo"<div id=\"listtitle\">";
echo"<h2>Property Name</h2> <h2>Location</h2> <h2>Guest Rating</h2><h2>Hotel Rank</h2><h2>Per night</h2>";
echo"</div>";
}
?><!--End of listtitle-->

<div class="cBoth"></div>       
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while($hotels_set = mysql_fetch_array($allhotels)){
          $room_rate =  rateforhotel($hotels_set['hotel_id']);
            if(!empty( $hotels_set['hotel_name']) && ($room_rate['hotel_id'] == $hotels_set['hotel_id'] )  ){
                      if($i % 2 == 0) { echo "<div id=\"innerlisteven\">"; } 
                       else 
                       {
                       echo"<div id=\"innerlistodd\">"; 
                       }   
                       echo"<h2><a href =\"#\">". $hotels_set['hotel_name'] ."</a></h2>";
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['country'] ."</h2>";
                       if(!intval($hotels_set['star'])){
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] ."</h2>";
                       }else{
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] . "<img src=\"img/repetimg/star.png\"/></h2>";
                       }
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] . "</h2>";
                       echo"<h2>". $room_rate['rate'] . "</h2>";
                       echo"</div>";
                       $i++;

           }//end of if()
    }//end of hotel while

        mysql_close($con);
       ?>
</div><!--End of details-->
<div id="advertlisting">

          <div id="search">search menu</div>

</div><!--End of adverts left-->

</div><!--End of end of maincontent-->
<div class="cBoth"><!-- clear Both--></div> 

<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

and the following code is the function itself

```
function hotel_by_country($country){
   global $connection;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE country ='{$country}'";
   $hotel_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);
   confirm_query($hotel_set);
   return $hotel_set;

 }

 function hotel_by_postel_code($postal){
   global $connection;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE hotel_postal_code ='{$postal}'";
   $hotel_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);
   confirm_query($hotel_set);
   return $hotel_set;
 }



function select_all_hotels(){
 global $connection;
   $query = "SELECT *
             FROM Hotels";

   $hotel_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);
   confirm_query($hotel_set);
   return $hotel_set;
 }
```

Comment: OR <-- in if is not like this use--> ||

Comment: That is not the reason because i tried both and it still does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many trail and error i was able to come to the solution and the following is the best option i found  maybe in the future someone my come up with the same problem. one thing to keep in mind is that the options in IF and Else can easily be moved into a function on separate file. and i also added one more Html menu to select the type of option i am search for in this case it is the filter menu.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');?>
<?php require_once("includes/header.php");?>
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php")?>
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['search']) &&  $_POST['search']!= "") {

                 if($_POST['filter'] == "HotelName"){
                 $search = $_POST['search'];

                  $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE hotel_name LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%'";
                  $allhotels = mysql_query($sqlquery, $connection) or die("Sorry Something wrong".mysql_error());


                 }else if($_POST['filter'] == "country"){

                 $search = $_POST['search'];

                  $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE country LIKE '%$search%' OR hotel_address LIKE '%$search%'";
                  $allhotels = mysql_query($sqlquery, $connection) or die("Sorry Something wrong".mysql_error());



                 }else if($_POST['filter'] == "Postal"){
                 $search = $_POST['search'];

                  $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE hotel_postal_code LIKE '%$search%'";
                  $allhotels = mysql_query($sqlquery, $connection) or die("Sorry Something wrong".mysql_error());
                 }

      }   


?>

<div class="cBoth"></div>
<div id="sep"></div>
<div id="mainContentSection" class="Calign">

<div id="detaillist">

<div id="searching" class="Calign">


  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="searchForm">
  <fieldset>
  <input type="text"  name="search" />
  <select name="filter">
  <option value="HotelName">Hotel Name</option>
  <option value="country">Country</option>
  <option value="Postal">Postal Code</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Search" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>      
</div><!--End of searching-->



<div id="listtitle">
     <h2>Property Name</h2> <h2>Location</h2><h2>Hotel Rank</h2><h2>Guest Rating</h2><h2>Per night</h2>
</div><!--End of listtitle-->

<div class="cBoth"></div>       
    <?php
    if(!isset($allhotels)){
    $allhotels = select_all_hotels();
    }
    $i=0;
    while($hotels_set = mysql_fetch_array( $allhotels)){
          $room_rate =  rateforhotel($hotels_set['hotel_id']);
            if(!empty( $hotels_set['hotel_name']) && ($room_rate['hotel_id'] == $hotels_set['hotel_id'] )  ){
                      if($i % 2 == 0) { echo "<div id=\"innerlisteven\">"; } 
                       else 
                       {
                       echo"<div id=\"innerlistodd\">"; 
                       }   
                       echo"<h2><a href=\"desti_list.php?details=" . urlencode($hotels_set["hotel_id"]).
                      "\">" . $hotels_set['hotel_name'] ."</a></h2>";
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['country'] ."</h2>";
                       if(!intval($hotels_set['star'])){
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] ."</h2>";
                       }else{
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] . "<img src=\"img/repetimg/star.png\"/></h2>";
                       }
                       echo"<h2>". $hotels_set['star'] . "</h2>";
                       echo"<h2>". $room_rate['rate'] . "</h2>";
                       echo"</div>";
                       $i++;

                /*
                 echo"<h3><a href=\"desti_list.php?details=" . urlencode($hotels_set["hotel_id"]).
                      "\">Find Out More</a></span></h3>";

                */       

           }//end of if()
    }//end of hotel while

        mysql_close($connection);
       ?>
</div><!--End of details-->
<div id="advertlisting">

          <div id="search">search menu</div>

</div><!--End of adverts left-->

</div><!--End of end of maincontent-->
<div class="cBoth"><!-- clear Both--></div> 

<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing (right) brackets `)` of the `empty` functions - one before the OR and one at the end of the condition).  
Change:

```
if(empty($allhotels = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue) OR empty($allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue))
```

to:

```
if(empty($allhotels = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue)) OR empty($allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue))){
```

Next, I would break this line into a few lines:

```
$allhotels1 = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue);
$allhotels2 = hotel_by_country($textvalue);
echo "allhotels1 = $allhotels1; allhotels1 = $allhotels1\n";//for debug
if(empty($allhotels1) OR empty($allhotels2){...
```

and one last thing - are you sure it should be `OR` and not `AND` ?

Comment: @SalimAlmughairi I don't understand your last comment

Comment: The record are being called but the problem is selecting one of the them rather then both or nothing at all.

Comment: if i use two var i will have to pull the record from the database twise below when i want to display that means i will have to have 2 while loop one for each condition if var1 the while(var1 = fetch...) and while(var2=fetch..). you see the way i did it is that if one of them works then it will still apply to the same while bellow. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_numermic($textvalue))
   hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue)
else
  hotel_by_country($textvalue)
```

Comment: none of them is numeric one is alpha numeric and the other is a text

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in this code

```
if(empty($allhotels = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue)) || empty($allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue))){
    $message = "There is no record in the database";
}
```

First you fill `$allhotels` with `hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue)`. Then you overwrite it with `$allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue)`.

Also, you should replace the `||` with `&&` because you only want the message when both functions return no values.

**Try**

```
$allhotels = hotel_by_postel_code($textvalue);
if(empty($allhotels)) {
    $allhotels = hotel_by_country($textvalue);
    if(empty($allhotels)) {
         $message = "There is no record in the database";
    }
}
```

Comment: what iam trying to check if the first is empty then assign the second to the same varibel so what do you think may be the problem.

Comment: The problem is that you overwrite the variable even if the first one is not empty. I have added some code in my answer.